# php mysql select results in Internal Server Error 500 by more than 351909 rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have following myslq select which works well in phpmyadmin. It returns 358631 rows.

In myphp it works as well till to the limit of 351909 entries.

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(time) as time, value1, value2 FROM tablename
```

Is there is a php limit? Any idea how to trouble shoot?

Comment: I suggest to edit memory_limit in `php.ini` in your apache  in line `479` edit `memory_size` to `256M` maybe work perfectly after editing this.

Comment: Thank you Eng_Farghly for you answer. Changed memory_limit = 256M in php.ini and works now!